# Эллиптическая кривая- сложение двух точек C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace lab3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x1 = 58;
            double y1 = 612;
            double x2 = 67;
            double y2 = 84;
            double p = 751;
            //y^2 = x^3-x+1(mod751)
            Console.WriteLine($"P({x1},{y1})");
            Console.WriteLine($"Q({x2},{y2})");
            Console.WriteLine($"p={p}");
            double l = Math.Pow(((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)),p);
            Console.WriteLine(l);
            double x3= Math.Pow((l*l - x1 - x2),p);
            Console.WriteLine(x3);
            double y3 = Math.Pow((l*(x1-x3)-y1),p);
            Console.WriteLine(y3);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите с вопросом почему консоль выводит ? где ошибка?

Comment: спасибо что нормально код отобразили...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что не хватает точности, в `.NET` значение `double` может быть равно от `-1.7976931348623157E+308` до `1.7976931348623157E+308`, тогда как в вашей программе происходит расчет числа примерно равного `-1.1E+1328`, поэтому оно и округляется в `-Infinity`.

Если вам нужны настолько большие числа, то для целых чисел, есть [BigInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1). В вашем конкретном примере он поможет (если пренебречь точность).

Для вещественных чисел в интернете можно поискать обертки поверх `BigInteger`, но насколько они хорошие я не знаю.

Также можно посмотреть в сторону оберток для [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).